# Macbook early 2009: does it has a maximum SD memory allowed

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card, compatibility, flash-memory

I have bought a couple of USB micro SD card readers. I have bought a couple of micro SD memories. None of them work well. The shop has told me that computers have a maximum memory allowed.

I have not found anything like that anywhere. Is there a maximum memory allowed? It depends upon the computer? It depends upon the reader? Maybe it is just that the three micro SD memories where corrupted?

By the way, I have formatted the micro sd memory with the following tool:https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ (OSX seems to be problematic to format because the compatibility with other devices. This association - software promises to solve that issue).

Comment: Define "do not work well" - are they showing up as read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent Support Article on Apple's website that addresses this:  [About the SD and SDXC card slot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204384)

> #### Does the SD slot work with cards that exceed 32 GB?
>
> Yes. However, most media manufactures preformat the media using common
> block-and-cluster sizes that do not approach the theoretical limits of
> a given file system. Most SD cards use the FAT32 file format.
> Preformatted FAT32 SD media is commonly available up to a capacity of
> 32 GB. Media that exceeds 32GB usually uses the exFAT file system.
> Some smaller capacity cards use the FAT16 file format. Preformatted
> FAT16 media is generally available up to a capacity of 2 GB. To
> determine which file system you are using with Mac OS X v10.6.5 or
> later, insert the media into the SD card slot, go to the Apple menu,
> select About this Mac..., click on More info..., click on Card Reader
> in the hardware section, and locate the File System field.

> #### Which SD card formats work in the SD card slot?
>
> Cards that conform to the SD 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x standards should work.
> **The SD card slot can use cards that are Standard SD (Secure Digital) 4
> MB to 2 GB, SDHC (Secure Digital High Capacity) 4 GB to 32 GB, and
> SDXC  (Secure Digital Extended Capacity) 4G B to 2 TB.** MMC can also be
> used in this slot. MiniSD, MicroSD, and higher density formats like
> MiniSDHC and MicroSDHC can also work with the use of "passive"
> adapters that conform to the width and thickness specifications listed
> above.

(Emphasis mine)

To format your SD card, you should use Disk Utility either using the GUI or via Terminal.

**Using Terminal:**

`diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ DiskName GPT /dev/diskN`

Where...

- `HFS+` = type of filesystem
- `DiskName` = Name you want to give the SD card (i.e. "Stuff", "My Photos")
- `GPT` = partition type
- `diskN` = disk identifier (i.e disk4, disk7, etc.)

For more details, see [`man diskutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html)

Comment: Did you say 2TB SD card? Wowzers

Comment: Not me...but Apple!  I just report the news!

Comment: So in short as the most common formatting option is FAT32 the conclusion is: a SD memory above 32Gb will work only if 2 conditions apply: it has been formatted as exFAT or NTFS and it's SDXC (Secure Digital Extended Capacity). Does it also apply for USB readers of SD cards?